# Access Spring bean definition properties at runtime for logging

Tags: spring

I want to be able to read the properties from certain bean definitions that are configured in my Spring configuration file (i.e. the one set by **contextConfigLocation** in my web.xml) at run time. I want to do this so that I can log property values so that I when I receive the log files for diagnosis I can see how the system integrators have set up the application.

Looking at the Spring debug logs I can see that they are read from the config file by the class `XmlBeanDefinitionReader`. I'm guessing there is a way that Spring provides for accessing the resulting bean definitions, but I can't find it.

By way of example these are the sort of bean definitions that for which I would like to read configurations.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl">
        <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/an_example_db</value>
    </property>
    <property name="user">
        <value>exampleuser</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>examplepwd</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.my.example.entity" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Please note that these are examples only. I'd like to be able to read properties for any bean definition if that is possible.

Comment: properties as in state or dependencies or application properties ?

Comment: It would be nice if you provide your application context configuration and show us which properties you need to help us on help you.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid providing example beans as they will create false-positive Google search results, but they will perhaps clarify what I am wanting so I have edited the OP to include some examples as requested.

Comment: spring-boot provides "actuators" for getting this sort of information

Answer (score 2):

You can create a bean that plugs in the post-construction phase of *all* beans created at which point you can perform you logging. This can be done by a bean that implements [BeanPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html).

Example:

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class BeanPostProcessorAuditChecker implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        System.out.println("Bean: " + beanName + " initialized with props: " + bean);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Things to note:

1. This bean can be defined using annotations (as depicted above) or XML config as usual.
2. The interface is intercepting *all* bean constructions.
3. The interface method implementations are expecting you to return the bean object.
4. In my example I just System.out.println but you really want to SLF4J or otherwise log. Also I'm trusting that the `toString()` method is implemented properly exposing the properties you are interested in.
5. If you want to filter the logging to happen only on a subset of beans and not for all beans you'll have to do that yourself in the body of the method with reflection

Snippet:

```
 if(bean instanceof DataSource || 
    bean instanceof SessionFactory) { log.debug("{}",bean); }
```

Since your business domain is not known some alternatives provided:

1. If you can pointcut your domain you want to plugin **AOP** is another alternative proxy approach.
2. You could expose **JMX** on the beans and consume externally (decoupled approach)
3. Another decoupled approach is publishing **Events** using [ApplicationEventPublisher](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationEventPublisher.html). This is fyi since not advisable in your case - you are interested in construction only state properties.

---

*Before Edit*

The beans you are demonstrating are 1) singletons (by virtue of Spring default scope) and 2) properties are not likely to be changing after bean setup (via set method calls).

Under these assumptions why aren't you amassing these properties values in a props file

```
database.driverClass=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.user=exampleuser
...
```

inject them in the context definition

```
...
<property name="user" value="#{database.user}"/>
...
```

and use the [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) to check the values.

Comment: I could put all the properties in a props file as you suggest, but as the purpose is purely diagnostic, not for system configuration, I just want a way to capture the bean properties in the log file. Your suggestion is still sound and I have up-voted it, but it's not quite what I want.

Comment: @GlennLawrence I understand now a bit better what you are trying to achieve therefore I've put together some extra info you might find interesting